# FileUpload if exist concat (counter) to the name

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a `fileupload` control, What I want to achieve is to concat a nuber to it, in order it to be unique.

All the posts that I found are talking about adding a `GUID` or `DateTime`

What i want to achieve is if the file exist in folder then the file name will be filename + (counter)

Example:

- The folder contain a file name- `file.png`

1) When I upload the same file name again, the existing one wont get delete and the new one will be called `file(1).png`.

2) When I upload the same file name again, (`file.png`) 
now the new file will be called `file(2)`

I have this code which handle the 1'st case but not the second:

```
public static string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
{
        string dir = Globals.Directories.GetCustomCategoryThumbnailDir();
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string fileNameWE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*" + fileExtension)
                                .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                .ToArray();
        string uniqueName = fileNameWE;
        int nextNum = 0;
        bool fileExist = false;
        string pattern = @"(.*)\(([\d]+)\)";

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var tempFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            var match = Regex.Match(tempFileName, pattern);

            if (tempFileName.Equals(fileNameWE))
            {
                // file exist in folder
                fileExist = true;
            }
            if (tempFileName.StartsWith(fileNameWE) && match.Success)
            {
                // there is a file name that start with "fileToUpload" name, we want to to take the number
                nextNum = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
                nextNum++;
            }
        }

        if (nextNum == 0 && !fileExist)
        {
            // filename dont exist                
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
        if (nextNum == 0 && fileExist) 
        {
            // the file name exist without (1)
            fileNameWE = $"{fileNameWE}(1)";
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
        else
        {
            var haveParentessis = Regex.Match(fileNameWE, pattern);

            if (haveParentessis.Success)
            {
                // we need to reset the nextNum
                nextNum = 1; 
            }

            // return the new unique name with suffix
            fileNameWE = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameWE, nextNum);
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's cause your `while` loop as pointed below is local to the function and thus the `counter` variable which is also a local variable won't be maintained it's current value. So in essence every request you get a new page instance and thus your `counter` will get re-initialized to 0

```
 while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, fileNameWE + fileExtension)))
 {
      fileNameWE = fileNameWE + "(" + counter.ToString() + ")";
      counter++;
 }
```

To get this done, you should store the `counter` variable in `Session` and retrieve it back. Don't forget it's an web application and thus the state won't be maintained unless you do it explicitly

```
 if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, fileNameWE + fileExtension)))
 {
      counter = (Session["counter"] != null) ? ((int)Session["counter"])++ : default(int);
      fileNameWE = fileNameWE + "(" + counter.ToString() + ")";
      Session["counter"] = counter;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the file name will always be concatenating with (counter), so if the file `filename(1)` exist in the folder the new name will be `filename(1)(1)`
and it's not what i want..

Comment: @E.Meir, no it will not be ... try once and see

Comment: i don't have problem with the numbers.. i have problem with the concatenation always happening..

Comment: @E.Meir, my bad ... it's because of the `while` loop. Change that to `if` condition ... see edit in answer if helps

Comment: @Rahul- its not the `if`.
I have updated my question code part, now it almost working but for example if the folder contains army(2)(1).png and i want to upload army(2).png it will result in the name army(2)(1).png but it need to be army(2)(1)(1).png

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by using regular expressions, below.  No persistent counter is required.  I think the concat problem is because there's nothing done to deal with the existing (1) suffix.  I coded this potential solution and hope it helps!  NB:  only lightly tested in debugger, and I am a novice

```
{
    string fileName = @"C:\Uploads\Testfile.bin";
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    string fileNameWE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    string pattern = @"(.*)\(([\d]+)\)$";

    var match = Regex.Match(fileNameWE, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int nextNum = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
        nextNum++;
        fileNameWE = $"{match.Groups[1].Value}({nextNum})";
    }
    else
    {
        fileNameWE = $"{fileNameWE}(1)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please take a look > i updated the code, i want to go through all the files in directory in one time of file system access, instead of using `FileExist` that will go to file system for each call.
So, i tried to use your code but its not working in the new case of getting all files in directory, can you take a look and help me solve?

Comment: I have updated it again, now it almost working but for example if the folder contains `army(2)(1).png` and i want to upload `army(2).png` it will result in the name `army(2)(1).png` but it need to be `army(2)(1)(1).png`

Comment: Can you clarify - in your question you said that when "file.png" is uploaded and it exists, to change the name to file(1).png and then file(2).png.  Your comment above this about files name file(2)(1).png seems to be in conflict with that.  Also my regex needs an adjustment which i will make (to match it against the end of the string, hopefully reduce bad matches)